# How do I do a 1-dimensional integration-by-parts if my (random) variable is of dimension d?

Tags: integration, probability-theory

I came across a proof of a characterization of a multivariate normal random variable and I have difficulty grasping the reason behind one particular line in the proof.

That line of proof goes this way:
Given $A$ a symmetric $d\times d$ matrix such that $G=A^{-1}Y\sim \mathcal{N}(0,I_d)$, i.e., $G$ is a multivariate standard normal vector, for some random vector $Y\in \mathbb{R}^d$.
Fix $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Then
$$
\mathbb{E}[G_k\cdot f(AG)] = \sum_{j=1}^d A_{jk}\cdot\mathbb{E}[\partial_j f(AG)], \text{ by 1-dimensional integration by parts (IBP)}.
$$

Note: $G=\{G_i: i=1, \ldots ,d\}, A=\{A_{il}: i,l=1,\ldots,d\}$ and $\partial_j f$ is the partial derivative of $f$ wrt the $j^{th}$ component.

My question is how do I do the the 1-dimensional IBP if my random variable is $d-$dimensional?

Answer (score 1):

Using Fubini, you can split your integral into $d$ one-dimensional integrals and then just do it the usual way.